# Codeigniter View: Applying CSS

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am learning CodeIgniter and trying to apply some style in my view css selector(main_row). But when i run project, i only get data without any style.Why?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Test View
    </title>
    <style>
        .main_row {
            border: solid thin;
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <h1>Solr Result</h1>
    <table>
      <?php
       foreach ($data as $rows) {
           echo '<tr class="main_row">';
           echo '<tr><td>'.$rows['content'].'</td></tr>';
           echo '<tr><td>'.$rows['url'].'</td></tr>';
           echo '</tr>';
       }
       ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I see, you have multiple `<tr>`, thus I would suggest using `class` instead of `id`. An `id` should be unique on the page, you see thats the difference in a class and id.

Also you are adding `<tr>` inside `<tr>`.

Comment: tried with class but still no luck

Comment: But still another prob exists. You are using tr inside tr. Try my answer posted below

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Test View
    </title>
    <style>
        .main_row {
            border: solid thin;
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <h1>Solr Result</h1>
    <table>
      <?php
       foreach ($data as $rows) {
           $html = "";
           $html .= '<tr class="main_row">';
           $html .=  '<td>'.$rows['content'].'</td>';
           $html .=  '<td>'.$rows['url'].'</td>';
           $html .=  '</tr>';
           echo $html;
       }
       ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this, should work

Comment: Whenever you loop and generate HTML, never echo it on every line. The moment you create an opening tag for HTML, the browser that is smart enough, creates the closing tag for it automatically.

To overcome this, always save the HTML content in a variable and echo the same when the loop ends

Comment: Accept as answer if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
you here using id for style and also using looping so, its for creating multiple table row id's. you just use given below code it will work fine. 

`<html>
```

Test View
    
    
        .main_row {
            border: solid thin;
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
    
`

```
`<body>
<h1>Solr Result</h1>
<table>
  <?php
   foreach ($data as $rows) {
       echo '<tr class="main_row">';
       echo '<tr><td>'.$rows['content'].'</td></tr>';
       echo '<tr><td>'.$rows['url'].'</td></tr>';
       echo '</tr>';
   }
   ?>
</table>
```

`

Comment: You should remove the context of the answer out of the code block.